# Why did I fail this audit question?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, new-users, first-post-review

I would like some clarity as to why I failed this audit question.  My thought was that this was a good question but did not belong on Stack Overflow because it was not of a programming nature. Evidently, I was wrong.

Audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11218322

Comment: If you feel that this question isn't on topic why haven't you voted to close the question yet?

Comment: down voting this and closing it out doesnt teach me anything

Comment: down voting/closing is not about teaching YOU something - its about keeping the community clean, so we can see the questions worth spending our time on.

Comment: @Jamiec Sure, but this is more about either re-affirming or properly adjusting his perception after being shaken. Which should be done *before* taking action when no longer sure enough.

Comment: sometimes a poor audit is picked. this is relatively common. Moderate the post how you feel it should have been moderated, and move on...

Comment: ok, thanks everyone.  I'm moving on

Comment: Regarding poor audits, really good suggestions are made to improve the situation by making it possible to report them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Comment: People that favor the [hadoop] tag tend the think that Hadoop deployment questions are on topic.  11 of them thought it was helpful, you normally fail an audit when you disagree with the crowd.  I suspect there would be much less of a need for audits if the machine would push reviews to the people that have the tag in their profile.  But that's not how it works, never hesitate the Skip button if the subject is murky.

Comment: @HansPassant: Now I'm confused: Do you say the hadoop people are wrong, or everyone else? Of course, Skip is always right.