# Can someone suggest a better place for my Hadoop question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I posted a detailed question about Hadoop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771710/can-hadoop-impala-run-on-disk-less-machines-within-an-hdfs-cluster a while back, and it was recently put on hold as off-topic.  Totally fine -- I got no answers and I am still looking.  I saw a number of other questions similar to mine here (and linked a few), so figured this was the best place.

Where should I post this question?

Comment: Aside: I think your question was used as an audit that someone complained about.  It was selected as an audit because of its score, but the user who failed the audit thought it was a poor choice and was told to close the question to prevent it from being used as an audit.

Comment: so, I've not looked in the question yet, but the close reason says "Should be asked on Super User" no? maybe try there? (again, haven't looked in the question itself)

Comment: @ryanyuyu: You mean [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316616/why-did-i-fail-this-audit-question).

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah that one.  Thanks.  I had a really hard time finding it (as in I didn't find it).

Comment: Hadoop configurations can be asked on [unix.se]  or [sf], given the question I would recommend SF

Comment: Thanks all -- I appreciate the advice and insight.  The audit feedback was really interesting  -- remarkable how people react to down votes and stuff.  But I guess even us engineers are human :-).  I'll close and repost on Server Fault and see how that goes -- the reason I asked here in Meta was that I didn't feel like Super User was the best option.